# Can't get internet to work right on Virtual PC

Tags: virtual-machine, internet-connection

I'm running Win7 on the main machine and XPMode in the Virtual PC. No matter what I try, I cannot get normal connectivity inside the Virtual PC. I seem to be getting something though, which is confusing. When I try to browse - all I have is IE on there, since I haven't been able to get online to get anything else. When I load up IE, I can get the MSN homepage and can even click around to an extent. But, when I try to go to google or yahoo, etc, I get an error page basically telling me I'm not connected to the internet.

When I ping google/yahoo/etc from a CMD prompt, I have 0% packet loss.

I've followed the instructions on this page:

https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/96184-windows-virtual-pc-connect-virtual-machine-network.html

to no avail. To be fair, I wasn't able to figure out step 8 on that page since the Virtual machine is XP and I don't know how to do that in XP.

I'm lost here and losing a lot of sleep over this, so if anyone can help, I'd be very appreciative.

Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend showing a screenshot if possible. There are a few things you'll want to note. XP is old. You'll need to let us know if it's running SP3. The fact that you can get to some sites on IE (version?) implies you do have some network access, along with ping. The version is important as plenty of sites don't allow the older IE to connect, such as IE 6/7. I know plenty of users that have to manually download chrome for xp, and install it using a USB.

Comment: Could you add a screen shot of VirtualPC screen and the command with the result of ping?

Comment: Windows XP didn't have "network type" profiles so you couldn't do Step 8 if you wanted to

Comment: I'll have to add screenshots when I get home, but I did check and the IE version in the VirtualPC said it had 128 bit encryption